# How can I parse an XML element to XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a problem that I still can not solve.

I have text that comes from a TextBox and it is something like that:

```
<assemblyIdentity name="MyAssemblyName" publicKeyToken="my1231key" />
```

I want to load it as an XElement because I need to do perform some changes on it and change its format.I also want to get a list of its attribute values.

It is imposible to assign it to something that can be initialized by string.The quotes that surround the attribute values are the problem (and other things maybe).

Simply said, I have it as a content that comes from the TextBox.Text and I want to load it to XElement so I can work with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `XElement.Parse` method

```
 XElement rootElement = XElement.Parse(textbox1.Text);
```

More Info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538477.aspx

Comment: I have been thinking if it transforms it automatically if I  get the value directly from the textBox.Text.

Now I am making unit tests for that method and I don't know how to mock it somehow so I can pass the 
<assemblyIdentity name="MyAssemblyName" publicKeyToken="my1231key" />  string to the method explicitly so I can finish the test.

The only one way possible so far is using the &gt; &lt; &quot;  escape symbols but I don't know if this is going to be equivalent to what will come from the textBox.Text

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
var element = XElement.Parse(myTextBox.Text);
```

works for me.

Or is there something wrong with this approach for you?

Comment: I can not simulate it in a Unit test. When I perform the unit test I have to pass a static string value to the method somehow so I can make the Assert at the end.

Comment: Could you update your question including your unit testing requirement (Or possibly ask a completely different question). Folks have answered the question as asked, but the question you want answered isn't the question you asked. Also provide as much information as you can on what you've already tried and show us the method you want to test (or show us what it looks like), also, show the same for the test method (what you think it should look like). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
// string from textbox
string xml = "<assemblyIdentity name=\"MyAssemblyName\" publicKeyToken=\"my1231key\" />";
```

And here is parsing of element:

```
var assemblyIdentity = XElement.Parse(xml);     
var name = (string) assemblyIdentity.Attribute("name"); // MyAssemblyName
var token = (string) assemblyIdentity.Attribute("publicKeyToken"); // my1231key
```